# inconsistent message "Permission denied (publickey).fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, bitbucket

This message appears when trying to do a `git pull origin master`

`Permission denied (publickey).fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Sometimes it is: `conq: unable to process command fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Sometimes it goes through i.e updates and retrieves  changes

#### The problem is the lack of consistency prevents me from locating the issue.

The issue disappears after running `git pull origin master` a few times and *actually retrieves changes*.

A few notes:

- had the repo + keys set up years ago and no changes since. Use it daily. This is new
- had the same repo set up on a remote machine using the same public/private keys about a few months ago to auto deploy
- using bitbucket as a host

Comment: Sorry, bitbucket had issues - issue fixed itself   http://status.bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, bitbucket had issues.

http://status.bitbucket.org/incidents/7cfk7tf054wp

issue fixed itself after they recovered